# Is $0$ an eigenvalue of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$ and $F$ which are $n \times n$ matrices ($n≥3$).

If $det(ABC)=0$, $B$ is invertible, $rank(C)=n$, nullity of $D$ is 2, matrix $E$ columns span $R^n$ subspace which has dimension 1 and $det(DEF)=0$.

The question is that is $0$ an eigenvalue of any of these following matrices: $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$, $ABCDEF$, $BC$, $BD$ and $CD$.

Which of my conclusions are wrong when I have answered that:

$0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $F$, $ABCDEF$ and $0$ is not an eigenvalue of the rest matrices.

Are there some matrices that have such situation that $0$ may or may not be an eigenvalue?

Answer (score 1):

- nullity of $D$ is $2$, clearly $0$ is an eigenvalue. Hence $0$ is an eigenvalue for $BD$ and $CD$ as well.
- $E$ is of rank $1$, it also have eigenvalue $0$.
- Since $D$ and $E$ are singular, we can't conclude about the singularity of $F$.